# Disposing bound object in Ninject

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, ninject

I am binding an object of class DonorContext (which derives from DbContext of EntityFramework) as below in Global.ascx as below.

```
kernel.Bind<DonorContext>().ToSelf().InRequestScope().OnDeactivation(DisposeDonorContext);
```

I was expecting that at end of request, Ninject will call the DisposeDonorContext method. But it never gets called.

What I could gather from web was that the objects of IDisposible types will automatically get their Dispose method called when they go out of scope. This is not happening in my case and hence I was trying the OnDeactivation() to dispose the DonorContext (which doesn't happen either).

Any ideas why the dispose is not happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ninject will automatically call the Dispose method of objects implementing `IDisposable` (at least that's what happened when I tested it with the latest version). If this doesn't happen for you I suspect that the problem is that you never use this `DonorContext` anywhere in your application. So it never gets instantiated and never gets disposed. For example if you had a controller which takes this context as constructor argument:

```
public class HomeController: Controller
{
    private readonly DonorContext _context;
    public HomeController(DonorContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

It should work. It would also work if you had a service layer that takes this context as constructor argument and then you use this service in the controller (with constructor injection). At the end of the day you must have a controller which takes some dependency which itself might be the DonorContext or some other dependency which itself depends on DonorContext (repository, service, ...) in order to trigger the dependency injection chain.

This being said working with a concrete type such as *DonorContext* in your controller kind of defeats the purpose of using Dependency Injection as you are hardcoding it.

Comment: Darin, Actually I am injecting Service Layer object UserManager in my controller. This UserManager object contains DonorContext dependency. I am using [Inject] attribute to inject dependencies. The UserManager is scoped in default ninject scope. I am sure that DonorContext object is created and injected in my Service Layer as I am using it to load data which is happening correctly.

Comment: Darin, I freshly installed Ninject.MVC3 package and now I can see the OnDeactivation() calling my method. Thanks for your help.

Comment: +1 and everything is true and correct, but just wanted to make it explicit that it's Ninject's System.Web integration as embodied in Ninject.MVC3 that's wiring this up to be the case - the catch all handling in Ninject is the GC-trigged Cache and Collect mechanism that, depending on your hosting context could cause the OP's observed issues re the Deactivation not happening directly in an appropriate place in the ASP.NET processing cycle